# Do you know how to generate the dist folder from a combined Angular and .Net Core Application using YAML CI/CD with Azure?

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-devops, yaml

I am trying to get my Angular/.Net Core application to produce the dist folder and show the index.html file and have tried both the classic pipeline and YAML.

But when I run the CI/CD pipeline using the YAML below it runs and gives the green light but doesn't actually deploy the application dist folder as expected.

It ends up showing the following error in the browser:

InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.

The YAML is below:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install    
    ng build --prod #--optimization=false
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

# Copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths (not folder paths)
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    contents: '**/dist' # Pull the dist directory (Angular)
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

#used to look up directory of published files
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory) 
    script: ls -R

#install .net sdk 
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Install .NET 5 SDK
  inputs:
    version: '3.1.x'
    packageType: 'sdk'
    

#restore nuget packages from build
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '9e1f...'

#perform build action
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build .Net
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

#perform publish
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True
    
#perform publish of artifact
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

The release looks good and gives a green light as well but then I get the above error.

I have tried changing the PathToPublish to add /dist afterward it and also tried adding CopyFiles tasks to try to get the dist folder to copy from the source to the target to no avail.

The release pipeline has this as the package to publish in the Deploy to Azure App Service portion of the release pipeline:

$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/drop/drop/...Web.NgClient.zip

Any help is appreciated in understanding why it isn't creating the dist folder and why it isn't serving up the index.html per the error above.

Comment: Please check Zach Sexton's suggestions, and if you need any help, please feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in this task:

```
    # Copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths (not folder paths)
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        sourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        contents: '**/dist' # Pull the dist directory (Angular)
        targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

The copy files task copies the **contents inside** of the folder specified, not the folder and its contents. [Read the Contents argument here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

You need to specify something like `targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist` to have it show up in a folder named dist.

It's probably generating all of your files, but at the root of whatever $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) is.

Comment: I tried updating the CopyFiles task to add the 'ClientApp' as well as 'ClientApp/dist' but then that step says 0 files were copied.

Comment: Start simple and try to get ahold of the output of your build after the npm build step so you can see what the structure is and go from there, you probably are missing a path somewhere simple but have no visibility. 

Also to be clear, you changed the target directory right? I think your source was probably correct.